# Function returning a char vs. a char* string in ARM

Tags: assembly, arm

I'm trying to mimic this function in ARM to replace another function in memory:

```
const char* myName() {
  return "0";
}
```

This function returns a single char. I have tried with GodBolt but it uses pseudo-instruction that left me confused on how LDR/LDRB works: [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/z/rjPPs6hbh)

I have been googling a lot but most of them uses ASM which again uses alot of pseudo-instruction. I have also read all documentation on ARM website regarding: [LDR/LDRB](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/j/arm-and-thumb-instructions/ldr--immediate-offset-), which tells me that LDR/LDRB can't use immediate value, it requires address (SP/PC addressing).

I have tried `LDRB R0, #30' but it seems to only work with Thumb. The workaround I can think of is to put #30 (ASCII of 0) in some register then loading it again as LDRB:

```
MOV R1, #30
LDRB R0, [R1]
BX LR
```

I think it is wrong because the `[R1]` would considered as address rather than taking the value `30` from it. I'm confused on what the proper way to solve this.

Comment: *"This function returns a single char."* No, it returns a pointer to a two-byte array of `char` containing `0` and `\0`. The array itself will be in a text segment (`.rodata` or similar) IIRC. A function returning a single char would look like this: `const char myName() { return '0'; }` (note no `*` after the `char` in the return type, and the character literal `'0'` instead of the null-terminated string literal `"0"`).

Comment: The problem is: since I'm trying to replace the function from memory (memory editing) it limits me to get the pointer each time. Is there a way to utilize stacks for this? In case there multiple char  @T.J.Crowder

Comment: No, you can't return a pointer to a local on stack because that will be freed when the function finishes. If you are patching a function you may have enough space for a constant, it's just 2 bytes after all.

Comment: I'm afraid my knowledge in this area is too far back (and wasn't ARM-based). Good luck with it though. But note the stack will disappear when the function returns, so probably not.

Comment: Unfortunately the original function only consist of 8-bytes: `LDR R1, [R0, #4] BX LR`, using STR to that [R0, #4] is also not possible since STR couldn't use Immediate value. Anyway thank you for the help @Jester

Comment: Any space elsewhere you could jump to?

Comment: The string data shouldn't be part of the machine code in the first place, so you still only need 2 instructions like clang generated in your Godbolt link.  The string data goes in a nearby literal pool; you're looking for a spare 2 bytes *between* functions nearby, which isn't already used as data by other functions.  Then `add r0, pc, #something` / `bx lr`, or find space for a pointer to the pointer and `ldr` it with a PC-relative addressing mode like clang did.

Comment: Perhaps I could allocate some memory to that but I'm afraid that it is going too far placed. Is there some limitation in PC-relative-addressing? As far as I know, most people uses PC-relative when it is considerably close in memory. But hey, your comment gave me some idea to perhaps bind different function that returns the same string; using B/BL/JMP @PeterCordes

Comment: Aren't there gaps for alignment between most functions that you could use?  Or are they already in use as literal pools?  Or was the code compiled with `-falign-function=0` or `2` (4-bytes, which means no gaps assuming ARM-mode.)  Yes, PC-relative addressing modes (and add-immediate) have fairly limited range, like maybe +-4096 or something on that scale, maybe a couple powers of 2 higher or lower.

Comment: The original function is `LDR R1, [R0, #4]`?  That's strange, because normally R0 is used for return values, not R1.  Is some nonstandard calling convention in use, or do you have a typo?

Comment: Sadly there's no gap at all, I assume because it was in ELF structure (.so library), so I could only depends on replacing existing memory. My only option was to use stacks (SP) or PC-relative. Currently function hooking (function jumping) works but it is kinda absurd to always have typing the text in the collumn in order to update the string in another function @PeterCordes

Comment: Are you in ARM or Thumb mode here?

Comment: It is ARM @NateEldredge

Comment: It looks like `ADR` in ARM mode lets you use a "modified immediate", basically an 8-bit value shifted by any even number of bits.  So you could have your target memory be further away, if you have enough flexibility of location to place it at just the right offset within some large unused block.  Regrettably we don't have the AArch64 version of `ADR`, in which they sacrificed a big chunk of the opcode space to allow you a 21-bit immediate displacement.

Comment: *I assume because it was in ELF structure (.so library)* - No, that doesn't imply that functions have to be head-to-tail with no padding for alignment.  But it turns out (https://godbolt.org/z/P4PqsoMYv)  clang and GCC's default looks like `-falign-functions=2`, only aligning to 2^2 = 4 bytes, so only GCC in Thumb mode ends up with any 2-byte NOPs for padding.  So your best hope is that some existing literal pools between functions have odd-sized data with a 2-byte gap left in a spot you can reach with `adr`.  Otherwise yeah, jumping somewhere far away for more code+data works.

Comment: @NateEldredge `ADR` in ARM mode is just `ADD` with `PC` as the second operand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you need to put in looks like this:

```
myName: adr     r0, str  @ load the address of str into r0
        bx      lr       @ return to caller
str:    .string "0"
```

This is 12 bytes of code which can be placed anywhere in the binary where executable code can be placed.  The string is placed in line with the code; this snippet is relocatable.

In case you are hex editing, this code corresponds to the following 3 words of data:

```
e28f0000  adr     r0, str
e12fff1e  bx      lr
00000030  .string "0"
```

Note that the byte order is little endian.